# Suppose $AB​=AC$, where $B$ and $C$ are matrices and $A$ is invertible. Show that $B=C$. Is this​ true, in​ general, when $A$ is not​ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $AB=​AC$, where $B$ and $C$ are matrices, and $A$ is invertible. Show that $B=C$. Is this​ true, in​ general, when $A$ is not​ invertible?
What can be deduced from the assumptions that will help to show $B=​C$?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is invertible, then:

$$AB = AC \Rightarrow A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}AC \Rightarrow B = C.$$

If $A$ is not invertible, $AB = AC \Rightarrow B =C $ does not work.

Consider for instance:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}~\text{and}~ C = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -5 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Notice that $A$ is not invertible. Moreover:

$$AB = AC = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$

but $B \neq C.$

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix $A$ is invertible, there exists an inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ with $AA^{-1}=I=A^{-1}A$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. The inverse matrix is uniquely determined.

If $AB=AC$ and $A$ is invertible, then multiplying with $A^{-1}$ from the left, using associativity and that $A^{-1}A=I$ gives $B=C$.

Comment: thank you for your answer